# How to fix error #thread error in lldb debugger

Tags: assembly, x86-64, lldb, cpu-registers

I am learning about the lldb debugger, and I am running a simple C program that prints out 'Hello World' a 100 times, but I get an error immediately I run the breakpoint in lldb

```sh
(lldb) breakpoint --set main
invalid command 'breakpoint --set'.
(lldb) breakpoint set --name  main
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`main, address = 0x0000000100000f30
(lldb) run
Process 1160 launched: '/Users/tijanilawal/codestudy/c-crash-course/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 1160 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f30 a.out`main
a.out`main:
->  0x100000f30 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x100000f31 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100000f34 <+4>: subq   $0x10, %rsp
    0x100000f38 <+8>: movl   $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
Target 0: (a.out) stopped.
```

The expected output should show me informations on the registers in assembly

Comment: What error are you talking about?  Looks perfectly normal to me, after you got the right syntax for setting a breakpoint at the label `main`.  If you want the debugger to print registers, you need to use a debugger command to do that.  IDK if it has a text-window mode like GDB's `layout reg`.

Comment: The error I am talking about is the point where the process stops. What I am trying to do is to show the state of the processors registers right before the program starts, and this just throws an error at me, I use the lldb compiler not gdb

Comment: **That's not an error!**  It's just showing you stuff about where and why you stopped.  Breakpoints are *supposed* to stop.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Am still very new to assembly and the entire lldb compiler in general. I found the matching lldb command for the `info registers` which is `register read`. Thank you for the heads up

Comment: You should probably [edit] your question to ask what you really want to know, or just google / read the lldb docs.